# What is a "localized message"?

Tags: java, exception

I have seen in several languages that (especially exceptions) offer *message* and *localised message* methods. But it is not clear to me what the difference is - do any of the following apply?

1. The *localized message* is for child classes to use. Why wouldn't they override the primary *message*?
2. Is this a physical location thing where the same *message* may be presented based on things like locale, timezone, etc.

Furthermore when should the *localized message* be preferred over the regular *message*? Or conversely, not?

Comment: Can you show actual code where you've seen that exceptions have localized messages? Otherwise, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one:

> Is this a physical location thing where the same message may be presented based on things like locale, timezone, etc.

Although it's usually just locale / culture, really.

Basically imagine that an error message of "The value must be greater than 0" might be represented as "La valeur doit être supérieure à 0" for French developers (courtesy of Google Translate; may not be idiomatic as an error message).

This is just applying the general concept of localization (making your code communicate in the language/culture of your user) to a specific case of error messages though.